# What common name can be used to classify LaTeX and office suites together?

Tags: phrase-requests, hypernyms

If someone wants to put LaTeX and office suites (especially the applications related to document preparation: Word, Publisher, Powerpoint, etc.) together in the same line in his CV/resume in the following way:

> Programming Languages: C++, Python
> (*): LaTeX, Microsoft Office, LibreOffice

What should be put in the place of '(*)' here?

The name *Word Processors* might seem to be a good candidate. But note that [LaTeX is not a word processor!](https://www.latex-project.org/about/#:%7E:text=LaTeX%20is%20not%20a%20word%20processor!)

From the chatrooms in TeX and EL&U SE, I have got some suggestions such as *Document Processing Systems*, *Desktop Publishing Systems*, *Digital Typesetting Systems*, etc.

Which common name or hypernym is currently more preferable and acceptable to use in this context?

Comment: It depends on quite what you're trying to convey and how specific you're trying to be. At its most generic, you could try "software suites".

Comment: @KillingTime To me, `software suites` is quite a broader genre. Here, I like to classify only the document preparation or typography-related tools.

Comment: One problem here is that Office/LibreOffice is a suite of applications, and LaTeX isn't really. Or: LaTeX is a text processor inasmuch as it takes a file as input and produces high-quality output. MS Word (for example) is a different thing altogether.

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, they work differently. But their target is related to a similar thing which is some kind of document preparation. Isn't it?

Comment: By including Microsoft Office and LibreOffice, you've broadened the scope beyond word processing. Wikipedia says "LibreOffice is a free and open-source office productivity software suite." So maybe "productivity software"? Or, if you don't want to represent yourself as having expertise in Microsoft Outlook, Access, OneNote, etc., then just say Microsoft Word if that's what you mean.

Comment: Why would **document preparation** not work? You've used it three times at this point, and to me that seems reasonably clear.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin yes, at this point, the `document preparation` or `document processing systems` are preferable to me.  But looking forward to knowing others' opinions and reasoning in this context.

Comment: Try: ***Other Skills:***

Comment: Or even ***Related Skills:***

Comment: As a hint, if you are not looking for a job in academia, it's highly unlikely that the employer will consider LaTeX a relevant skill.